# Moment of Inertia of a Cylinder about Central Diameter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

I am attempting to calculate the moment of inertia of a cylinder of mass M, radius R and length L about the central diameter i.e. perpendicular to the axis of the cylinder.

A standard derivation uses Parallel Axis Theorem along with Perpendicular Axis Theorem which can be found at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/icyl.html

My attempt at a solution uses the basic formula $I=m{ r }^{ 2 }$ in Cylindrical Coordinate System.

$dm=\rho rdrd\theta dz$  where $\rho =\frac { M }{ \pi { R }^{ 2 }L } $

Taking the central diameter as the axis, a small element $dm=\rho rdrd\theta dz$ undergoes circular motion with radius $z$ . Substituting in the formula $I=m{ r }^{ 2 }$, we get $$I=\iiint { { z }^{ 2 }dm=\iiint { { z }^{ 2 } } \rho rdrd\theta dz } \\ I=\rho \int _{ 0 }^{ R }{ rdr } \int _{ 0 }^{ 2\pi  }{ d\theta  } \int _{ -L/2 }^{ L/2 }{ { z }^{ 2 }dz } \\ I=\frac { M }{ \pi { R }^{ 2 }L } \frac { { R }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } 2\pi \frac { L^{ 3 } }{ 12 } \\ I=\frac { M{ L }^{ 2 } }{ 12 } $$

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Please ask a specific conceptual question rather than the open-ended "what have I done wrong here?" question, as check-my-work problems are off-topic for this site. (The issue is that they are not of much use to anyone who is not *you* and this site is not specifically about helping *you*, it is about writing down all the physics questions anyone could possibly have and hopefully offering good answers for all of them.)

Comment: The distance from your chosen axis to a point of mass in the cylinder is not z. z is the distance from the central plane circle to any other plane circle. The distance is something like $\sqrt{z^2+(r\cos\theta )^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are trying to get the moment of inertia about an axis that is perpendicular to the central axis of the cylinder.  In this case, your differential element of inertia is not $z^2 dm$.  Instead, let $s$ represent the distance between your axis and the point in question, then the element of inertia is $s^2 dm$.  $s$ is different from $z$ because the elements in the cylinder will generally not lie right on the $z$ axis.  The limits of integration will also be more complicated.  What you have done should be a decent approximation if the cylinder length is much greater than its radius.

Comment: But isn't the element moving in a circle of radius z when rotated about the axis?

Comment: Only in the limit of a very narrow cylinder.  Generally, most elements will have some displacement from the z axis and that will add at least a small amount to their radius.  Before you get too far, make sure that you are being asked to do this in that limit.  The corrections I am suggesting would make the problem much more difficultl.

Comment: @bob.sacamento "much more difficult" is a bit of an overstatement; one has  for the rotation about the $y$-axis $\int_0^R dr~\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}dz~\rho~\left(\sqrt{z^2 + r^2\cos^2\theta}\right)^2,$ squaring the square-root gives an integral of $r z^2 + r^3 \cos^2\theta$ and the integral of that cos-squared over $0\lt\theta\lt 2\pi$ is just $\pi$, so this is just $2\pi~\frac12 R^2~\frac23 (L/2)^3 + \pi~\frac14 R^4 ~L$, no?

Comment: @CRDrost  Yeah, I think you're right.  I was just off handedly figuring that the integration limits become more complicated, but you are right AFAICT.